# In R, negative subsetting produces unexpected results with slightly larger numbers

Tags: r, subset

In R,

`print((1:20)[-(15:18)])`

prints the list of integers from 1 to 20 excepting 15 through 18, as expected.

But

`print((1983:2010)[-(1992:1994)])`

prints the list of integers from 1983 to 2010, including 1992 through 1994. The negative subsetting is not working.

What's going on here? I know R can have trouble with extremely large numbers, but I would not consider these numbers extremely large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the numeric index.  In the second example, we don't have a vector of length > 1994, but in the former case, there is

```
length(1983:2010)
#[1] 28
```

The way to deal with this to use `%in%`

```
v1 <- 1983:2010
v1[!v1 %in% 1992:1994]
```

Or use the index based on the original length of the `vector`

```
v1[-((length(v1)-2):length(v1))]
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to have to count the positions they would occupy. Is there a way to do this in one line? Or do you have to name the list first, then subset?

Comment: @lost Both the solution I posted are one-line.  I don't know what you meant by one-liner.  If `v1<- 1983:2010` is considered as another line, it is just to create the object

Comment: I guess I meant one-liner as in one statement? Not sure if that's the right nomenclature. What I had i mind was what neilfws gave in his comment

Comment: Didn't mean to offend. Functionally it's pretty much the same, but do you think ``print((1983:2010)[!1983:2010 %in% 1992:1994])`` is preferable stylistically? Because you don't have to name a variable, store it in memory, etc.

Comment: @lost I didn't got offended or anything.  I am just trying to help.  When you do the sequence `1983:2010`, you are asking R to do a job, if the same job is repeated twice, I think there may be some efficiency problem (for large vectors).  Instead create an object once and remove it once it is done `rm(v1)`.  Lets say that you do this for 1000s of sequence, which one would be faster - creating the sequence two times or once?

Comment: Good point. In this case, the vectors are small, but I can see why in general it may make more sense to create an object. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The values in square brackets refer to the position of the number in the vector, not the number itself.

In your first example, numbers 15-18 also occupy the positions 15-18.

In your second example, numbers 1992-1994 don't occupy positions 1992-1994. They occupy positions 10-12. So you could use:

```
print((1983:2010)[-(10:12)])
```

Comment: Got it. Is there an easy fix without having to count the indices?

Comment: You could do `print((1983:2010)[!1983:2010 %in% 1992:1994])`.